# Get array of all entities from entity reference field

Tags: 8, nodes, entities

On one of my content types I have a taxonomy term reference field that allows for multiple values. Normally if I wanted the term from a field I'd simply do

$node->field_taxonomy_term->entity;

However this doesn't work if there are multiple entities. Normally I would expect getValue() to do the trick but that just gives an array of the ids with target_id as the key. I sort of have a round about way of getting them with this method

```
    $entity_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy');
    $ids = [];
    foreach ($this->field_taxonomy_term->getValue() as $item) {
        $ids[] = $item['target_id'];
    }
    $entities = $entity_storage->loadMultiple($ids);
```

But when getting one is as simple as $node->field_name->entity I had a feeling that I'm doing more work than necessary. Is there a simpler way to obtain an array of entities from a field or is what I'm doing the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't say for sure on that specific field but usually there's the referencedEntities() method you can call

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3AreferencedEntities/8.4.x

So something like this perhaps:

$entities = $node->field_taxonomy_term->referencedEntities();